# The title et al

Tags: theoretical-biology

I have found the extension "et al" with biologists from different nationalities like : Avery et al ; Taylor et al etc.

My question :
1. What does it mean? 
2. Why only biologists?

Comment: It is just to abbreviate the names of the authors that is used in all fields of knowledge. For example, if I have to refer to [this paper](http://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/690673) that has 9 authors, I will not write every name, I will just write Gilbert et al. 2017. I am not sure why you would care more about nationalities than whether they prefer chocolate over caramel. They are just authors.

Comment: I am voting to close because your question is off-topic here but would be on-topic on [Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) (although they will likely say "Just google it!").

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Latin phrase *et alia* (abbreviated et al.) means **and others**.

It is not limited to biologists, nor those of different nationalities. If I refer to [this computer graphics article](http://physbam.stanford.edu/~fedkiw/papers/stanford2002-02.pdf), I can refer to it as "the paper written by Henrik Jensen, et al., regarding physically based modeling of fire..."

Note that the expansion of et al. can also be *et alii* and *et aliae*, which are the masculine and feminine forms, respectively; *et alia* is the neuter form.

Comment: Actually, in Latin "al." can be the abbreviation of 3 things: *alii*, *aliae* and *alia*. The first is masculine, the second is feminine and the third is neuter (all of them are nominative plural).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - So how do we know to which "et al." is referring? And if the genders of the authors are mixed, why isn't it, *et. al. et. al.*?

Comment: @anongoodnurse you don't. Since "al." is the abbreviation for *alii* and *aliae*, it covers any combination of researchers: all male, all female or mixed. Also (and this answers your second question), Latin is a very "sexist" language: a group of one thousand women is *aliae*, but a group of one thousand women with a single man among them is now *alii*. So, a mixed team is just *et alii*.

Comment: Actually, Latin is so "sexist" that, even possessing neuter pronouns, if you're taking about a person of unknown gender you use the masculine pronoun.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - I was pilling your leg. :) I love Latin; I taught it for about six years. But there is no one - and I mean *no one* - I know that shares that love of Latin, so you were the victim. Please forgive me. :)